# If a ticketless traveler makes $4$ trips, what is the probability that he/she will be the caught during at least one of the trips?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> The probability that a ticket-less traveler is caught during a trip is $0.1$. If the traveler makes  $4$ trips, what is the probability that he/she will be the caught during at least one of the trips ?

Comment: What is the probability that she will get away with it $4$ times in a row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probability of getting caught at least once = 1 - Probability of never getting caught

Probability of getting caught on a given trip = $0.1$

Probability of not getting caught on a given trip = $1-0.1=0.9$

Probability of not getting caught on all the four trips = $0.9\times0.9\times0.9\times0.9=0.6561$

This is because each trip is independent of the rest.

Thus,

Probability of getting caught at least once = $1-0.6561=0.3439$

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, you can approach the problem directly.

Notice that we have $n = 4$ (presumably) independent trials (trips) with probability $p = .1$ of success (getting caught). Then the number of times being caught $N$ follows a binomial distribution $\text{Bin}(4,.1)$.
Then, we are asked
$$P(N\geq 1) = \sum_{k = 1}^4\binom{4}{k}(0.1)^k(1-0.1)^{4-k} = 0.3439.$$
Of course, taking the complement approach is much more efficient.